# Where is the creature slaughter dome?

Tags: borderlands-2

i've looked around for it but I cant find it. Is it in the main menu or a specific location in the game? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The Creature Slaughter Dome is located in the Natural Selection Annex of the Wildlife Exploitation Preserve. It is only available if

- you have pre-purchased Borderlands 2 at select retailers, or
- purchased Creature Slaughter Dome separately on Steam, or
- current character was in a network game with another eligible character and has visited the location in said game.